# Token for CARTs (closed captions) API Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, closed-captions

I'm trying to make a successful call to Microsoft's [closed captions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/meeting-apps-apis?tabs=channel-meeting%2Cguest-user%2Cone-on-one-call%2Cdotnet%2Cparticipant-join-event%2Cparticipant-join-event1#cart-url) but keep getting a 404 error, specifically I get

> { error: 'Meeting not found or is not started.' }

I've created the live meeting and enabled captions but keep getting this error.

For the meeting id I followed the documentation to create a URL encoded JSON string from an object consisting of tenant id, organizer id, thread id and a message id (defaulted to 0)

I also tried getting the actual meeting id via the SDK on a Teams app I'm developing in conjunction with this feature.

In both instances I get the same error message.

Regarding the authentication, I tried Client Credentials Flow and Authorization Code Flow to get the `token` required for the endpoint. Neither token changes the outcome.

Does anyone have an idea how to make a successful request to this endpoint?

Comment: Please read [ask], and then edit your question to provide a [mcve]. Right now you haven't provided anything except for an error message (an error that doesn't really contain much detail at all)

Comment: Could you please confirm that the meeting you are trying to access is currently active and that captions are enabled for that meeting? Also, make sure that the meeting ID you are using in your request is correct. If you're using the URL encoded JSON string, ensure that all the components (tenant id, organizer id, thread id, message id) are accurately represented.

Comment: Ensure that the authentication process is successful. The token obtained from either Client Credentials Flow or Authorization Code Flow should grant the necessary permissions for accessing the closed captions API. Double-check the token's scope and permissions. Please verify that you are using the correct URL format for the closed captions API endpoint.